# Do setBackgroundColor() call onDraw()?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-view, android-custom-view

Working with a custom view I noticed something is weird:

I noticed that `setBackgroundColor()` invokes `onDraw()`
so far so good
And since I wanted to create recursive calls to onDraw, I put `setBackgroundColor()` inside `onDraw()` expecting that `onDraw()` will be forever called by the nested `setBackgroundColor()` .

However, that didn't happen, domething strange happend:
The initial `onDraw()` code was fired, and when the `setBackgroundColor()` line was executed the code of `onDraw()` kept going as normal (as if it is not a recursive call) and only when `onDraw()` returned, was it that `onDraw()` was called again.

So I said to myself, maybe `setBackgroundColor()` only raises a flag for the system to queue a call to `onDraw()`, and maybe the system waits for the initial `onDraw()` call to return, and only than calls it a second time.
But when the second `onDraw()` was called (due to the `setBackgroundColor()` alleged system flag) the code ran normally, and did not invoke a third call.
How is it possible for `setBackgroundColor()` to cause a recursive call only a single time?

This is the code:
counter reached 2 and stopped:

```java
public class MyView extends View {
    int counter;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        counter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        counter++;
        setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling it only two times:

1. When calling `super.onDraw()`
2. `setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`

When calling `super()` doesn't call `MyView.onDraw()` because the rules of inheritance. You should study inheritance in java.

Comment: if setBackgroundColor() calls onDraw(), and (as seen in my code) onDraw() obviously calls setBackgroundColor() than they suppose to call each other forever

Comment: You are wrong. You call `MyView.onDraw()`->`super.onDraw()`->`setBackgroundColor()`(called from super)-> returns super.onDraw() ->`setBackgroundColor()` (called from myView) -> end. Please study inheritance before insisting in nonsenses [Using the Keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: if i call setBackgroundColor() from another place in the code it invokes onDraw() also, so the same suppose to happn when calling it from within onDraw()

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve here with a dead loop. Calling setBackground in onDraw is a bad practise. Meanwhile, setBackground doesn't trigger onDraw immediately. It invalidates the view, which calls onDraw at some point in the future.

To make the view to draw again, you can also call requestLayout() or invalidate().